# JFXPanel Dynamic Sizing

Tags: java, swing, javafx, resize, pack

In the process of converting from Swing to FX.  We currently have JFXPanels within JInternalFrames.  When initially displaying a new screen, everything is fine because we are first setting the scene and then calling the pack() method on the JInternalFrame.

The problem lies with screens where new Nodes get added (typically based on ChoiceBox selection) to the screen that require the panel to be wider.  It currently just tries to fit the Nodes in causing some of the labels to become ellipsis.  What is the best way to go about having the JFXPanel/JInternalFrame resize when needed?